# Targetting a class with :last-child

Tags: css

I have a class `.side-box { margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }` and what I'm trying to do is target the last `.side-box` in the DOM and apply `margin-right: 0;` to it with **no jquery** and **no extra class** to overwrite `margin-right`. In this way I have only a `padding: 10px;` wrapping the three boxes.

I tried:

```
.side-box:nth-child(2) {
     margin-right: 0;
}
```

and

```
.sidebars:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
```

but didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**FIDDLE HERE**: http://jsfiddle.net/qL7wx5pp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it. You want to select the last `sidebars` and then get the `side-box` inside. Something like this:

`.sidebars:last-child > .side-box`

http://jsfiddle.net/qL7wx5pp/2/

Comment: So, `.sidebars:last-child` would be the last `sidebars` in the DOM, right?

Comment: @Labanino in this case, yes. But not always. `last-child` always targets the element which is the last child of its parent. So if you have multiple `wrappers` with multiple `sidebars`, `last-child` will apply to every `sidebars` that happens to be the last child in its own `wrapper`

Answer (score 2):

If you read [about `last-child` here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) is says:

> The :last-child selector matches every element that is **the last child
>   of its parent**.

I have highlighted **the last child of its parent** because that is what is causing your issue.

You have not applied the margin to the `sidebars` but to the `side-box`
So this wont do what you want.

```
.sidebars:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
}
```

Now to target the correct `side-box` you need to realise how your DOM is structured.

You have a parent `wrapper` with 3 child `sidebars`
To target the last `side-box`, you need to target the last `sidebars`

Hence selecting `sidebars:last-child` is the correct target div. But the margin needs to be reset on the `side-box` div that is again a child of the last `sidebars` div

So the correct selector would be:

`sidebars:last-child > side-box`

`side-box` that is a child of the last child `sidebars`. See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qL7wx5pp/3/)